# Youtube data API, query within channel lead to unexcpected results

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use Youtube Data API for a project, the goal is seeking for a keyword in a channel and show the response to the user. I used the Search for "snippet" part and launched it querying for a specific keyword and specifing the channel id but the response didn't include all the videos that I was expecting. For instance, let's say that the channel has 10 videos with "c" charachter in the title, setting the q field with "c" value will return only one video. 
On the other side, if I search for a whole word it returns some videos with that word on title and some other videos that doesn't have it, neither in description. The order criteria in this case seems to be ok (from the strongest match to the most weak), but I don't know if all of this is working fine.

Is this a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an order on the search, the issue seems to be solved.